# Comparing 2 objects in PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I apologies if the question is not quite right, as I'm not sure of the correct wording / syntax for this question...

```
Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | Where { $_.Guest.GuestFullname} | Sort Name |Select-Object Name, @{N=”SelectedOS”;E={$_.Guest.GuestFullName}}, @{N=”InstalledOS”;E={$_.Summary.Config.GuestFullName}} | Out-GridView
```

How would I compare and match the data of "SelectedOS" and "InstalledOS" to be output.

So for example the current script would output:

```
Name                                                          SelectedOS                                                    InstalledOS
----                                                          ----------                                                    -----------
VM-Demo-CCMIVR-1                                         Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)                        Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
VM-Demo-vMCD2                                            Other 2.6.x Linux (32-bit)                                    CentOS 4/5/6 (32-bit)
VM-Inf-CUC-10-5                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
VM-Inf-CUCM-10-5                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
VM-Inf-DC01                                              Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)                        Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
```

However i only want to see:

```
Name                                                          SelectedOS                                                    InstalledOS
----                                                          ----------                                                    -----------
VM-Demo-CCMIVR-1                                         Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)                        Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
VM-Inf-CUC-10-5                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
VM-Inf-CUCM-10-5                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
VM-Inf-DC01                                              Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)                        Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read you right, you want to compare and only show machines where "SelectedOS" and "InstalledOS" are the same. To do that you need the `-eq` in your `Where` statement. Like this:

```
Where { $_.Guest.GuestFullname -eq $_.Summary.Config.GuestFullName }
```

So your code becomes.

```
Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | Where { $_.Guest.GuestFullname -eq $_.Summary.Config.GuestFullName } | Sort Name |Select-Object Name, @{N=”SelectedOS”;E={$_.Guest.GuestFullName}}, @{N=”InstalledOS”;E={$_.Summary.Config.GuestFullName}} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that since `SelectedOS -eq InstalledOS` you could probably omit one of the two in the output. That may just be my OCD side coming out though! ;) Good answer by the way

Comment: That did it, it's so obvious now.  I was trying to compare the output not the initial query.  :(